# what's the meaning of high precision and very much low recall of a recommender system ?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommendation-engine

I have not much knowledge about precision and recall. I have design a recommender system. Its gives me 
**precision value = 0.409**
and **recall value = 0.067**
*we know that precision and recall are inversely related though I am not sure about that*. Then what about my system??

> Its that ok if I can increase precision value and decrease recall
>   value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision is the percentage of your correctness when you choose positive since it depend on  you prediction when you choose positive only (Depend on model positive prediction only ) an. In the other side , Recall measure whats you percentage of correctness in the positive Class (i.e  in the All positive cases  what is the percentage of true decision that the model take).

Comment: then what about my above system?

Comment: The Recall is too low. This means in the  cases that the  real answer is True,  your model choose correct with percentage of 0.067 which is too low. Suppose you have 100 case that there answer is True, your model  in 6.7 case decide that  the answer is true and in the 93.3 the  decide that the answer is false.

Comment: that means I also have to increase the value of recall

Comment: Yes you have :)

Comment: Was it Useful answer ?